# Showing a dialog through tile service gives theme error

Tags: android, service, themes

I have a TileService and everything goes fine until I click on the button in the quick settings tray which is supposed to show a simple dialog. When I click on the quick settings button the app crashes and gives the following error - You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

```
package com.dev.main;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.service.quicksettings.Tile;
import android.service.quicksettings.TileService;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class MyTileService extends TileService {

@Override
public void onTileAdded() {
}

@Override
public void onStartListening() {
}

@Override
public void onClick() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("title");
    builder.setMessage("message");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        }
    });

    showDialog(builder.create());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by replacing the alert dialog build declaration with this line - `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar));`

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog` that needs context with `Theme.AppCompat`, but TileService is extended by a simple `Context`.
You can import `android.app.AlertDialog` to solve it.